# Codeigniter - Encode, Decode JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

There are two tables such as Package and PackageService. The main tables are Package Table. I joined these tables between package.packageService = packageService.packageServiceId. I want to hold some data in Package Table with JSON using id. I have an edit page. I want to when I edit some package, I can choose some package multiple features with checkbox afterthat I can show these features on Package View and Package Edit View. How can I do this with JSON clearly?

My Model:

```
public function packages()

    {

        $this->db->select_max('packageId', 'MaxPackageId');
        $this->db->select('IF(packageParent = 0, packageId, packageParent) as parent', FALSE);
        $this->db->from('package');
        $this->db->group_by('parent');

        $subquery = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
        $this->db->reset_query();
        $this->db->select('package.*, packageService.*');
        $this->db->from('package');
        $this->db->join("($subquery) t1","t1.MaxPackageId = package.packageId");
        $this->db->join('packageService', 'package.packageService = packageService.packageServiceId', 'LEFT');

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();



    }
```

Package View:

```
<section id="main-content">
    <section class="wrapper site-min-height">
        <!-- page start-->
        <div class="row">
            <!--price start-->
            <div class="text-center feature-head">
                <h1> PACKAGES </h1>
                <p>Choose Your Special Package Plan. </p>
            </div>

            <?php foreach($packs as $get) { ?>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
                    <div class="pricing-table <?php if ($get->packageNameEn == 'Platinum') { echo 'most-popular'; } ?>">
                        <div class="pricing-head">
                            <h1> <?php echo $get->packageNameEn; ?> </h1>
                            <h5><del>€ <?php echo $get->packagePrice ?></del></h5>
                            <h2><span class="note">€</span> <?php echo $get->packagePriceCut ?> </h2>

                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            // I want to show package features with JSON here <?php echo $get->packageServiceNameEn ?>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="price-actions">
                            <a class="btn" href="javascript:;">Get Now</a>
                            <a class="btn" href="<?php echo base_url("package/edit/$get->packageId"); ?>">Edit</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <!-- page end-->
    </section>
</section>
<!--main content end-->
```

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're asking. You want to store JSON in the database using an ID that is found in the JSON itself? or just plain store JSON in the db?

Comment: I want to plain store JSON in db such as ["1"] ["2"] etc.

Comment: You want to insert json into a column? Just `json_encode` and insert. You want to `serialize()` data and insert it into a column? Just do it?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: I know the question is answered already but you can just create a 'mediumtext' or 'longtext' column in your database and store it like you would anything else. The problem with that it's hard to then use that JSON data to help with any queries in the database, like searching for a specific key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you wan't to save a list of ID's from `packageService` table as feautures.
With this you need to remove this line

```
$this->db->join('packageService', 'package.packageService = packageService.packageServiceId', 'LEFT');
```

And when you want to display the feautures:

In controller:

```
// get all feautures
$this->data['feautures'] = $this->db->get('packageService')->result();
```

In your view:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
// I want to show package features with JSON here 
<?php 
$get->packageService = json_decode($get->packageService);
foreach ($feautures as $key=> $feauture) { 
    if(in_array(feauture->packageServiceId, $package->packageService))
        echo $feauture->packageServiceNameEn ;
}
?>
</ul>
```

To work this, `packageService` must be a json string with id's of  `packageService` table.